# how can i find the NAME and CITY Using ID Child Node?

Tags: xml, vb.net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mainele>
  <strtele>
    <id>1</id>
    <Name>sahil</Name>
    <City>kadi</City>
  </strtele>
  <strtele>
    <id>2</id>
    <Name>imran</Name>
    <City>kadi</City>
  </strtele>
</mainele>
```

i have used following code to get id from xml file in combo box.

```
Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        doc.Load("D:\sahil practice\sd.xml")
        Dim list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("id")
        For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In list
            Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(item.InnerText)
        Next
```

Result is  "SAHIL" and "Kadi" when i select the id = 1 in combo box...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim doc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    doc.Load("D:\sahil practice\sd.xml")
    Dim list = doc.GetElementsByTagName("strtele")
    Dim name, city As String
    For Each item As System.Xml.XmlElement In list
        If item.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText = ComboBox1.SelectedItem Then
            name = item.SelectSingleNode("Name").InnerText
            city = item.SelectSingleNode("City").InnerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```